# i am trying making a program to compare between .txt files only using system calls

Tags: c, linux, compare

I got a school project the assignment is:

To create `comp.c` to compare between content of two files using only
system calls: `open(),` `read(),` `close()` (Cant use `strcmp()`, `strncmp()`, `strlen()`)
`comp.out a.txt b.txt`
 `comp.out` return 1 if the two files are not identical and 2 if they are the same
To see the result you should use the command: `echo $?`

this is my code:

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc , char * argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("something wrong with variables\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    char* filename1 = argv[1];
    char* filename2 = argv[2];
    char* addr1;
    char* addr2;
    struct stat stat_p1;
    struct stat stat_p2;
    int fileSize1=0,fileSize2=0;

    if( stat (filename1, &stat_p1) == -1)
    {
        printf("error occurred while attempting to stat %s\n" , filename1);
        exit(-2);
    }

    if( stat (filename2, &stat_p2) == -1)
    {
        printf("error occurred while attempting to stat %s\n" , filename2);
        exit(-2);
    }

    if((fileSize1=stat_p1.st_size) != (fileSize2=stat_p2.st_size)) //checks if the size is different than its not the same file.
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int fd1,fd2;
        if((fd1 = open(filename1 ,O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        {
            printf("error opening file %s\n",filename1);
            exit(-3);
        }
        if((fd2 = open(filename2 ,O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        {
            printf("error opening file %s\n",filename2);
            exit(-3);
        }

        addr1 = mmap(NULL, fileSize1+ 1, PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE, fd1, 0);
        if (addr1 == MAP_FAILED)
        {
            printf("mmap failed\n");
            exit(-4);
        }

        addr2 = mmap(NULL, fileSize2+ 1, PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE, fd2, 0);
        if (addr2 == MAP_FAILED)
        {
            printf("mmap failed\n");
            exit(-4);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<fileSize1+1;i++)
        {
            if(addr1[i] != addr2[i])
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        close(fd1);
        close(fd2);
    }
    return 2;
}
```

i compile using `gcc -o comp.exe comp.c`
than i am trying to compare between 2 text files
i run this command `./comp.exe 1.txt, 2.txt`
and it fails around:

```
 if( stat (filename1, &stat_p1) == -1)
{
    printf("error occurred while attempting to stat %s\n" , filename1);
    exit(-2);
}
```

and I have no clue been on it for hours any suggestions what's wrong
big thanks

Comment: My guess is that you are passing along invalid absolute / relative paths to the files. Maybe try printing those out and double check that they are indeed correct.

Comment: _return 1 if the two files are not identical_ , and you are checking only their sizes to determine it, `if((fileSize1=stat_p1.st_size) != (fileSize2=stat_p2.st_size))` , what if files have same size but they are different.

Comment: Can you use `perror`?

Comment: `int` is not always large enough for the size. The correct type would be `off_t`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem has to do with how to invoke your program and get the result. I've compiled it and everything works as expected: 1 is returned if they are different, and 2 when they have the same contents.

In order for that to work, you need to a) launch bash on Linux or in Windows (using for instance the WSL layer). Then type:

```
$ ./fcmp fcmp.c fcmp2.c
$ echo $?
2
$ ./fcmp fcmp.c randomfile.txt
$ echo $?
1
```

If you plan to do the same in "native" Windows, then the variable you need to check is ErrorLevel. So the code would be like:

```
c:> fcmp fcmp.c fcmp2.c
c:> echo %errorlevel%
2
c:> fcmp fcmp.c randomfile.txt
c:> echo %errorlevel%
1
```

(Disclaimer: I could not try it since I do not own a Windows machine.)
If that does not work, try creating a BATCH file such as:

```
@echo off
fcmp %1 %2
echo %errorlevel%
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer i didn't quite understand what to do i am working on a ubuntu platform and in terminal what do i need to do to run it correctly and compare between 2 .txt files everything is in the same folder btw

Comment: Follow the instructions in the first block of code. If you are working in Ubuntu, then `make  cmp` is enought to obtain an executable, and the suffix `.exe` is not needed.